# Why is the multiplicative order of perfect powers modulo $p$ smaller on average?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, multiplicative-order

I've been trying to analyse by myself for recreational purposes what would be a "better" base to use instead of the common decimal one. Part of what should make a base better is to have simpler/smaller fractional representations. In this sense, for all bases from 2 to 100, I computed the periods of the inverses of the first $10^5$ primes and calculated their average, or, equivalently, the average of the order of all theses bases modulo $p$ in the given range, as given in the expression below.
$$\frac{1}{10^5}\sum_{i=1 \\ \text{gcd}(p_i,b)=1}^{10^5}\text{ord}_{p_i}(b)$$
The result is shown in the following graph.

[image]

There are significant dips at perfect powers, specially at the squares, which means that, overall, the fractional representations of rationals, using these numbers as a base, are much "smaller" than the rest of the numbers on average. Not only that, but the average is not strictly decreasing as the power increases, and even powers have lower averages than odd powers. Could that have something to do with the fact that the order is even about 2/3 of the time? What explains this behavior? There also seem to be some of the form $5n^2$ with average order slightly higher.

Comment: Well, the perfect powers are also powers modulo $p$, so you already have an exponentiation before you start exponentiating to find the order; it makes sense that that would tend to reduce the order. I think the more interesting question about this graph is to quantatively explain these particular reductions; I'll try to post an answer that does that.

Comment: This turned out more complicated than I'd expected. I've got it mostly worked out, but it'll take me a while to write up a proper answer.

Comment: @joriki "the perfect powers are also powers modulo p, so you already have an exponentiation before you start exponentiating to find the order" That makes a lot of sense, but the average of 32 ($2^5$) is greater than that of 16 ($2^4$), which is counter-intuitive. Hope you find the answer!

Comment: The reason that $b=m^2$ is smaller is that square integers are squares modulo every prime $p$ for which "squares" makes sense—but that's all odd primes, since $p-1$ is always divisible by $2$. The reason that $b=m^4$ is smaller still is that 4th power integers are 4th powers modulo every prime $p$ for which that makes sense—which is all primes $p\equiv 1$ (mod $4$), or about half of them. But 5th powers only make sense for primes $p\equiv 1$ (mod $5$), which is only about a quarter of the primes.